# How to protect /docs endpoint in FastAPI using Azure AD (fastapi_msal)?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi, openapi, azure-ad-msal

How to connect the Authorize button in protect under `/docs` endpoint in FastAPI application to Azure AD?

Is it possible to make Authorize button to trigger a popup for the sign in window? Similar to how its done in this example [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-single-page-app-react-sign-in-users) for NodeJS?

```
if (loginType === "popup") {
  instance.loginPopup(loginRequest).catch((e) => {
    // error code
});
```

So the token is generated and stored in a cookie in local storage and sent on each request.

I have protected my endpoints so it checks for a valid access token in each API request that is sent in authorization bearer token using OAuth2PasswordBearer from FastAPI. This works when it sent from frontend. However I have not been able to get this token myself from AzureAD on the FastAPI application. I have not found any way to trigger the pop in FastAPI documentation.

I assume that I should be able to use:
https://pypi.org/project/fastapi_msal/

Here is the pop up for sign in (Used in many sites and places):
[image]

Comment: custom apirouter which check for `/docs` endpoint and implement the authentication would be a one of solutuion

Comment: is it possible to trigger the sso popup window to sign in? Also to automatically support multifactor authentication if needed as in example in the question for nodejs?

Comment: You can display a login form using `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` where user can enter username and password. Then you send this password to AD that provide you with a access_token. This only works if you dont have multi authentication enabled in AzureAD. But less safe for the user since the username and password willbe sent to you not directly to AzureAD (Probably okay internal use and small usecases where you have trust).